# ../x86_64-linux-gnu/libarmadillo.so: referencia a `H5Ovisit1' sin definir collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: compiling, c++

I cannot compile anymore a cpp file with armadillo library.
I get this:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libarmadillo.so: referencia a `H5Ovisit1' sin definir
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It started to fail after I installed the Armadillo library version 9.700.2 (previously I had the version 9.200.4).